# JavaScript "keydown" works incorrectly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am learning JS and trying to make a "terminal" in a browser. The only thing I need right now is to display a key that was pressed. For example, user presses "k", "k" displays on the screen, user presses "d", "kd" displays on the screen. That's how should it work. But in my case, when I press key "r" it reacts like control + r and the page reloads, many other keys react as control + key. But when I press "w", it displays as "w" instead of closing the tab. I need keys to display correctly. [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsMDq.jpg)

```js
"use strict";

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(a) {
    text.innerHTML += a.key;
});
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #222;
}

#text {
    color: #0f0;
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1000px;
    padding: 25px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html">
<html lang="eng">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <p id="text"></p>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Looks like there is nothing wrong in your code. Check your keyboard status.

Comment: it's ok https://jsfiddle.net/eugensunic/vuyhxdb0/2/

Comment: which operating system are u using?

Comment: You forgot to define `text`. `var text = document.getElementById('text')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am building a similar project right now, and I use a hidden input element like

```
<input id="hidden_input" style="opacity:0;width:0;height:0;">
```

Before we add everything else, we need to make the element always focused:

```
var hidden_input_element = document.getElementById("hidden_input");
//Focus
hidden_input_element.focus();
//When unfocused, focus again
hidden_input_element.addEventListener("blur", hidden_input_element.focus);
```

And then have an "input" listener on that element that will call when the input element is updated (with text, not when using CTRL keys etc.)

```
hidden_input_element.addEventListener("input", updateMirror);
```

The updateMirror function will update an element that is visible, like in your case the element with the ID of "text".

```
function updateMirror(){
document.getElementById("text").innerText = hidden_input_element.value;
}
```

Later, we need to handle some events

```
hidden_input_element.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){

//When user presses enter, empty the input and send it to a handler.
if(e.keyCode == 13){
//Send input to handler
handleInput(hidden_input_element.value);
//Empty input
hidden_input_element.value = "";
}

//If the input would be changed, it might be helpful to update the mirror
updateMirror();
});
```

And then create that handler function (handleInput):

```
function handleInput(input){
//Create a list of commands that the user can use.
}
```

I hope this works, here is a snippet:

```js
var hidden_input_element = document.getElementById("hidden_input");
//Focus
hidden_input_element.focus();
//When unfocused, focus again
hidden_input_element.addEventListener("blur", hidden_input_element.focus);


hidden_input_element.addEventListener("input", updateMirror);

function updateMirror(){
document.getElementById("text").innerText = hidden_input_element.value;
}

hidden_input_element.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){

//When user presses enter, empty the input and send it to a handler.
if(e.keyCode == 13){
//Send input to handler
handleInput(hidden_input_element.value);
//Empty input
hidden_input_element.value = "";
}

//If the input would be changed, it might be helpful to update the mirror
updateMirror();
});


//This print function is to print a text in the log
function print(value){
//Create a text element
var new_line_element = document.createElement("p");

//Make the text look fancy
new_line_element.classList.add("line");

//Set the text on the element
new_line_element.innerText=value;

//Append the element in the log div
document.getElementById("log").appendChild(new_line_element);
}


function handleInput(input){
//This will happen when the user presses enter.

print(input);
}
```

```css
body {
background-color: #222;
}

.line {
color: #0f0;
font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
width: 300px;
height: 10px;
/*
I set the width and height from 1000px to 1px, and removed padding 25px
*/

/*
Also, I recommend adding these:
*/
white-space: pre-wrap;
word-break: break-all;
}

/*
This is specified for the input, and not the log messages.
This is to add a cursor to see where you are.
*/
.input::after{
content:".";
color: transparent;

border-bottom: 2px solid #0f0;
position: relative;
top: -4px;

animation: cursorblink;
animation-duration: .5s;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes cursorblink{
50%{opacity:0;}
}

#hidden_input{
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html">
<html lang="eng">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<title></title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="log"></div>
<p id="text" class="line input"></p>
<input id="hidden_input" style="opacity:0;width:0;height:0;">
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Blink (Chrome) does not comprehend `event.key` like other engines (browsers) do. Also don't use the `keypress` event, it's not as reliable (can't recall offhand why) though make sure you test your code before using it in a live environment.

```
function event_key()
{
 var r = false;
 if (Object.defineProperty)
 {
  Object.defineProperty(KeyboardEvent.prototype,'key',
  {
   get:function ()
   {
    var r;
    var k = {'65':'a','66':'b','67':'c','68':'d','69':'e','70':'f','71':'g','72':'h','73':'i','74':'j','75':'k','76':'l','77':'m','78':'n','79':'o','80':'p','81':'q','82':'r','83':'s','84':'t','85':'u','86':'v','87':'w','88':'x','89':'y','90':'z','8':'Backspace','9':'Tab','13':'Enter','16':'Shift','17':'Control','18':'Alt','20':'CapsLock','27':'Esc','32':' ','33':'PageUp','34':'PageDown','35':'End','36':'Home','37':'Left','38':'Up','39':'Right','40':'Down','45':'Insert','46':'Del','48':'0','49':'1','50':'2','51':'3','52':'4','53':'5','54':'6','55':'7','56':'8','57':'9','91':'OS','92':'OS','93':'Menu','96':'0','97':'1','98':'2','99':'3','100':'4','101':'5','102':'6','103':'7','104':'8','105':'9','106':'*','107':'+','109':'-','110':'.','111':'/','112':'F1','113':'F2','114':'F3','115':'F4','116':'F5','117':'F6','118':'F7','119':'F8','120':'F9','121':'F10','122':'F11','123':'F12','144':'NumLock','145':'ScrollLock','186':':','187':'=','188':',','189':'-','190':'.','191':'/','192':'`','219':'[','220':'\\','221':']','222':'\''}

    if (k[this.keyCode]) {r = k[this.keyCode];}
    else {r = 'Unknown Key';}
    return r;
   }
  });
 }
 return r;
}

window.onkeydown = function(event)
{
 var k = (event.key) ? event.key : event_key();
 console.log('Key pressed: '+k);
}
```